# Reading variables from txt file and saving them into the class objects as arrays c++

Tags: c++, loops, class, object, getline

I am trying to get variables from a txt file which looks like;

```
1 Prince Heins 25
2 Lady Bridgette 29
3 Tony Ann 223
4 Lucy Phoenix 35
```

and here is my code but i can not get the variables from txt file to myArray. I created them with the number of line by using getline and linenumber is equal to **linecount** . Then i created many objects which is equal to linecount number. Next step was getting the variables from txt file line by line and i tried to use while(pbin) which is my read function. I am trying to send variables to class by using set functions which includes my strings and integer but i get an compile error:***[Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream}' and 'void')*** I checked the examples but none of them solved my issue.
Couldn't get the issue and fix it. I would be glad if someone helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class contact{
private:

    int listno;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string phonenumber;
        
public:
    contact(){
        this->name="Unknown";
        this->surname="Unknown";
        this->phonenumber="Unknown";
        this->listno=0;
    }
    contact (string name,string surname,string phonenumber){
        this->name=name;
        this->surname=surname;
        this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
        this->listno=0;
    }
    contact(int listno,string name,string surname,string phonenumber){
        
        this->name=name;
        this->surname=surname;
        this->listno=listno;
        this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
    }
    void setListno(int listno){
        this->listno=listno;
    }
    
    int getListno(){
        return listno;
    }
    
    void setName(string name){
        this->name=name;
    }
    
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    void setSurname(string surname){
        this->surname=surname;
    }
    
    string getSurname(){
        return surname;
    }
    
    void setNumber(string phonenumber){
        this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
    }
    
    string getNumber(){
        return phonenumber;
    }
    
    
    void showInfos(){
        cout << "Listno: " << this->listno << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << this->name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << this->surname << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << this->phonenumber<<endl;
        
    }
    

};



int main(){
    int mListno;
    string mName;
    string mSurname;
    string mNumber;
    ifstream pbin("phoneData2.txt");
    string line;
    long linecount;
    contact* myArray = new contact[linecount];
    for(linecount=0;getline(pbin,line);linecount++);
    if(pbin.is_open()){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<linecount;i++){
            while(
            pbin >> myArray[i].setListno(mListno);
            pbin >> myArray[i].setName(mName);
            pbin >> myArray[i].setSurname(mSurname);
            pbin >> myArray[i].setNumber(mNumber);
            )

        }
    }
    pbin.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**edited:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class contact{
private:

    int listno;
    string name;
    string surname;
    string phonenumber;
        
public:
    contact(){
        this->name="Unknown";
        this->surname="Unknown";
        this->phonenumber="Unknown";
        this->listno=0;
    }
    contact (string name,string surname,string phonenumber){
        this->name=name;
        this->surname=surname;
        this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
        this->listno=0;
    }
    contact(int listno,string name,string surname,string phonenumber){
        
        this->name=name;
        this->surname=surname;
        this->listno=listno;
        this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
    }
    void setListno(int listno){
        this->listno=listno;
    }
    
    int getListno(){
        return listno;
    }
    
    void setName(string name,int count){
        this->name=name[count];
    }
    
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    void setSurname(string surname){
        this->surname=surname;
    }
    
    string getSurname(){
        return surname;
    }
    
    void setNumber(string phonenumber){
        this->phonenumber=phonenumber;
    }
    
    string getNumber(){
        return phonenumber;
    }
    
    
    void showInfos(){
        cout << "Listno: " << this->listno << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << this->name << endl;
        cout << "Surname: " << this->surname << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << this->phonenumber<<endl;
        
    }
    
    friend istream & operator>> (istream & in, contact & con){
        in >> con.listno >> con.name >> con.surname >> con.phonenumber;
        return in;
    }

};





int main(){
    ifstream pbin("phoneData2.txt");
    string line;
    long linecount=0;
    contact* myArray = new contact[linecount];
    for(linecount=0;getline(pbin,line);linecount++);
    pbin.seekg(0);
    if(pbin.is_open()){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<linecount;i++){
            if(! (pbin >> myArray[i]))
            {
                cout << "The contact is not found." ;
            }
        }
    }
    pbin.close();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you post a Question, please be specific about the problem you're having ("i get an compile error" is not adequate) and try to reduce your code to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest and simplest version that reproduces the error; you will usually find the bug yourself while doing that.

Comment: Many mistakes in the above code, too many for a concise answer usable by future askers with a similar problem--because no one will have the same combination of mistakes. One of the big ones is trying to stream into a setter. Typically you stream into a variable, and then use the variable as the argument to the setter or write a `>>` overload to stream directly into the object and ignore the setters.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your comment. I would like to write a >> overload to stream directly into object. What is the way to do that? I was using setters to reach private part. I feel like i am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `contact` a `>>` overload

```cpp
    friend std::istream & operator>> (std::istream & in, contact & con)
    {
        in >> con.listno >> con.name >> con.surname >> con.phonenumber;
        return in;
    }
```

and then in `main`, the `for` loop becomes

```cpp
        for(i=0;i<linecount;i++){
            if (! (pbin >> myArray[i]))
            { // failed to read a contact
                // do something here to clean up the mess
            }
        }
```

To round out a couple of the other mistakes,

```cpp
int main(){
    ifstream pbin("phoneData2.txt");
    string line;
    long linecount = 0; // otherwise you don't know what number linecount starts at
    contact* myArray = new contact[linecount];
    for(linecount=0;getline(pbin,line);linecount++);
    pbin.clear(); // Clear the error flag from hitting the end of the file
                  // Needed when building to older C++ Standards
    pbin.seekg(0); // rewind the file
    if(pbin.is_open()){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<linecount;i++){
            if (! (pbin >> myArray[i]))
            {
                // do something here to clean up the mess
            }

        }
    }
    pbin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I did what you suggest but there is something wrong with for part. I always get the error line which is //failed to read a contact part. I am editing my code for you to see clearly. I tried to get cout of operator but i couldn't. Read the overload stream topics but still couldn't get it. Last one touch please to understand how can i cout my arrays?